# array.contains(array) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, contains

Is there an easy way of knowing if and array contains all elements of another array?

Example:

```
var myarray = [1,2,3];
var searchinarray = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

searchinarray contains all elements of myarray, so this should return true.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *contains* function should only visit members of the array to be contained that exist, e.g.

```
var myArray = [1,,2];
var searchInArray = [1,2,3];

contains(myArray, searchInArray);
```

should return true, however a simple looping solution will return false as `myArray[1]` doesn't exist so will return *undefined*, which is not present in the *searchInArray*. To easily avoid that and not use a *hasOwnProperty* test, you can use the Array [*every* method](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.prototype.every):

```
function contains(searchIn, array) {
  return array.every(function(v){return this.indexOf(v) != -1}, searchIn);
}
```

so that:

```
var a = [1,,3];
var s = [1,2,3,4,5];

console.log(contains(s, a));  // true
```

You can add a *contains* method to all instances of Array if you wish:

```
if (typeof Array.prototype.contains == 'undefined') {
  Array.prototype.contains = function(a) {
    return a.every(function(v, i) {
      return this.indexOf(v) != -1;
    }, this);
  }
}

console.log(s.contains(a));      // true
console.log(s.contains([1,9]));  // false
```

You may need a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Polyfill) for browsers that don't have *.every* (IE 8?).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation of that function:

```
function contains(a, s) {
   for(var i = 0, l = s.length; i < l; i++) {
      if(!~a.indexOf(s[i])) {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

This shows that it does what you describe:

```
> var myarray = [1,2,3];
> var searchinarray = [1,2,3,4,5];
> contains(myarray, searchinarray)
false
> contains(myarray, [1,2])
true
> contains(myarray, [2,3])
true
```

Comment: This should test that `s[i]` actually exists, or use a method like *forEach* that only visits members of `s` that exist. e.g. should `contains(s, [,,1])` return true or false?

Answer (score 0):

```
function compare(array, contains_array) {
 for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if(contains_array.indexOf(array[i]) == -1) return false;
 }
 return true;
}

compare(myarray, searchinarray);
```